# Can Eldritch Knights Use Spell Foci?

Tags: dnd-5e, fighter, spell-components

Can Eldritch Knights Use Spell Foci and if so what things do they use as them?

Comment: Hey @ElZiko, welcome to the site! It looks like your question has already been asked and answered at the place that is linked above. Don't worry though, posting a duplicate question is not a bad thing since it helps point to the other question. Hope to see you around!

Comment: Related: [Eldritch Knight and Arcane focus](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/108335/eldritch-knight-and-arcane-focus)